# Iterate through each element of a dataframe column in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to iterate over each element of a column in a dataframe. This is my code:

```
distances=[10,20,30]
node_colors = {}
for distances, color in zip(sorted(distances, reverse=True), iso_colors):
subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, result2010['nearest_osm'], radius=distances, distance='time')
for node in subgraph.nodes():
node_colors[node] = color
nc = [node_colors[node] if node in node_colors else 'none' for node in G.nodes()]
ns = [20 if node in node_colors else 0 for node in G.nodes()]
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_color=nc, node_size=ns, node_alpha=0.8, node_zorder=2,
                    bgcolor='k', edge_linewidth=0.2, edge_color='#999999')
```

`result2010['nearest_osm']` is a column of a dataframe named `result2010`. And in my code i need to iterate over each element of this column (fourth line of the code)

But when i run my code i got this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Someone can help me? Thank you

Comment: What's a "dataframe"? Don't you mean dictionary?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.